# Distributing ParallelStream Processing for JMS Message Creation

Tags: java, activemq-classic, apache-kafka

I'm trying to scale the below sample program that creates a simple JMS message and concurrently pushes it to the same queue.  The sample program currently takes around 20 seconds on a single quad core host. Can anyone recommend some changes to the below to improve the performance?  The 20 second measurement is just for the below parallel stream processing line:

```
test.parallelStream().forEach(e -> sender.sendMessage(e));
```

One approach I can think of is to spread out my Collection ("test") to a few hosts which then process the collection concurrently in chunks by configuring each thread to have its own threadpool. One downside to this is fault tolerance and having to put the proper constructs in place to make sure each threadpool doesn't process the same message.

Another approach would to use a more performant/concurrent broker like Kafka

**Please note** that whatever async thread approach I take that I do need to be able to control how many messages are being sent from those threads to another application as they only support a set amount concurrently. Any other ideas?

**Full Source:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class Sender {
    private static ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    private static Connection connection = null;
    private static Session session = null;
    private static Destination destination = null;
    private static MessageProducer producer = null;

    public Sender() {}

    public void sendMessage(String test) {
        try {
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
            message.setText(test);
            producer.send(message);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
            factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
    ((ActiveMQConnectionFactory)factory).setUseAsyncSend(true);
    ((ActiveMQConnectionFactory)factory).setOptimizeAcknowledge(true);
    connection = factory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    destination = session.createQueue("SAMPLEQUEUE");
    producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

        List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
            test.add(Integer.toString(i));
        }
        Sender sender = new Sender();
        test.parallelStream().forEach(e -> sender.sendMessage(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a potential thread-safety issue in your code: MessagProducer::send() is not guaranteed to be safe to call from multiple threads.

Comment: Please ignore that for now as it will be moved to Spring JMS at a later point in time, this was just an example.  thanks.

Comment: What is the expected throughput messages/s and what is the size of each ? Your example is not relevant enough, an integer as a string will take around 10 bytes, it is quite small compared to real world use cases.

Comment: @Minh-TrietLÊ, we expect 100k 10 times per week all in one shot.  The message will have a int and a String (160 characters or less) and then a timestamp, so very small.

Comment: @c12 Using Kafka, you can achieve 100k/s of small messages of 100 bytes. Here is the report https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out MessagProducer is not guaranteed to be thread safe, but nor is Session.

Anyway, on the point:

1. I would strongly advise against using the default stream api for IO operations as it is using one thread pool for all operations and the thread pool is limited to the amount of cores plus you can't specify a timeout. You should be using Executor instead: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    for (String msg: msgs) {
        executor.execute(() -> send(msg)); 
    }
```

2. If you do not have to guarantee message delivery you can change message delivery mode to NON_PERSISTENT, this speeds up sending because there is no overhead from message storage and guaranteed delivery.
3. In reality though you do not need to do thread management yourself as ActiveMQ has async support, meaning your messages can be acknowledged on separate threads as long as you don't have to guarantee delivery: http://activemq.apache.org/async-sends.html
4. If you do need to guarantee delivery then instead use PERSISTENT message delivery mode (the default) inside of a JMS transaction to batch send your messages (a sort-of all or nothing approach). This gives a big performance boost as you only do the actual sending during commit. [https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#createSession(boolean, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#createSession(boolean,%20int))
5. Enable optimizeAcknowledge in ActiveMQ to speed up the message broker itself: http://activemq.apache.org/optimized-acknowledgement.html
6. Lastly you can set session acknowledgment mode to Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE so that messages are lazily acknowledged in the background but this can produce duplicate sending of messages so the consumer side needs to be prepared for this using a unique id or similar

Of course you should not use all of these methods together, just use common sense on what fits the other.

Comment: highstakes thanks for the pointers! I will be porting the MessageProducer and Session out to Spring JMS, this was just an example.  I didn't see a clear way to spilt a collection of records across a Executor based threadpool.

Comment: @c12 added example, though you won't need to use this, just rely on ActiveMQ thread management. Alternatively you could use executors and batch send for example every 10k messages only inside transactions

Comment: I'm assuming ConnectionFactory.setUseAsyncSend(true) and DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT can be combined, correct?  I see a 2X improvement when I setUseAsyncSend(true) and DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT vs setUseAsyncSend(true) and DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT.  It's about 2.5seconds for 100k messages single threaded vs 5seconds for the same amount.  Ideally I want the right balance between performance and delivery guarantee which is why I was looking at using DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT and parallel processing.  I've updated my example above with the config which is taking 5s for 100k.

Comment: You can combine it but I would be very surprised if parallel processing made any difference here (if not made the performance worse), as async is already parallel. Parallel processing only makes sense if you use transactions to batch messages and process multiple batches of messages on separate threads.

Comment: just to clarify, ConnectionFactory.setUseAsyncSend(true) and DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT can be combined and there will be 0 message loss?

Comment: PERSISTENT does not guarantee that sending cannot fail, it guarantees that if sending succeeds then the message will be delivered to a consumer. If you use async persistent messages outside a transaction you cannot manage sending failure, only if you pass an async handler (I think with the producer.send method) to be called when the sending completes (fails or succeeds). I never had to use this, transactions are way easier to manage because the commit itself is synchronous even if the individual messages are async.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what is said above, I would also concentrate on how you consume the messages. If your receiving end App can process a limited amount of messages at the same time, it doesn't matter how many you messages you are sending at the same time as they will all wait in the queue until your receiving app is ready to consume them. So, say your receiving app can take care of 10 requests concurrently. I would set up 10 consumers to your queue where each consumer reads an incoming request from the queue only after it processed the request it dealt with before. This way your speed of incoming messages doesn't matter so much (except of worrying of overflowing the queue). And your app will always process no more then 10 requests at the same time.

Comment: Hi Michael, the receive app can receive up to 3k request concurrently so I had planned to standup 300 consumers on 10 hosts.  I do need to run some profiling to see how many consumer threads each host can handle.  Thanks.